# DocuSign: How to verify Webhoook requests?

Tags: docusignapi, webhooks

On this page: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/webhook-status, the last section is called: `There’s more`. And there you can read that there are 3 ways to check that DocuSign is making the web hook request:

1. you can check the SSL/TSL certificate of the webhook caller (DocuSign).
2. set DocuSign to digitally sign the data
3. DocuSign publishes the IP address ranges

If we examine all these options we have:

1. This is false, you can't check the SSL certificate of who is making the request to you. SSL certs are designed to be used by clients connecting to servers to check that there is no man in the middle attack. And only the client can verify the cert of a server, not the other way around.
2. I can't find on the page any mention how to set the signature, and most importantly, how to check it.
3. The link provided to the Public IPs: https://trust.docusign.com/en-us/trust-certifications/ip-ranges/, does not work.

My questions are:

1. Where can I find some documentation about the signature process?
2. Where is the page with the public IPs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do that is to create an HMAC key and use that to confirm that the calls are authentic.

Here is a full article on how to do that - https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/connect-hmac

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for reporting the out of date documentation. I've filed an internal bug report, DEVDOCS-1565, to have it updated.

As Inbar says in his answer, these days, the best solution is HMAC. You can also combine it with Basic Authentication if you're using DocuSign webhooks at the account level.

HMAC gives you the guarantees that the message did originate from DocuSign and that the message was not altered in transmission.

#### Don't set up a server on the Internet

The old way of receiving webhook messages was to set up a server that is accessible on the public internet. Due to the costs and Information Security issues creating and maintaining a service on the Internet, these days I suggest that you skip it.

Instead, use a cloud PAAS (AWS, Azure, Google Cloud, etc etc) to receive and queue the messages. Then, from behind your firewall, you can dequeue and process them. (With no changes to your firewall.)

See the [**Connect-** series of code examples](https://github.com/docusign?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=connect-%20in%3Aname&type=&language=).

#### Mutual TLS for checking the client's certificate

Note that you **can** check the certificate of a client. This feature of the TLS (ne SSL) protocol is called *Mutual TLS* and is supported by DocuSign webhooks.

But HMAC is better since it also guarantees message integrity.